# How to make a custom LaTeX symbol

Tags: latex

I don't suppose anyone can help with a custom TeX symbol? I need a `\sqsubset` with a `\cdot` in the middle of the subset symbol.

I tried using some suggestions from other questions I found but they all ruin the spacing of the subset symbol.

Comment: This is better-suited on [tex.se].

Answer (score 6):

You can overlay symbols `\sqsubset` and `\cdot` to make them a unit, and vary its size based on the style it's used in.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\sqsubsetcdot}{
  \mathchoice
    {\mathrel{\ooalign{$\sqsubset$\cr\hidewidth$\cdot$\hidewidth}}}% \displaystyle
    {\mathrel{\ooalign{$\sqsubset$\cr\hidewidth$\cdot$\hidewidth}}}% \textstyle
    {\mathrel{\ooalign{$\scriptstyle\sqsubset$\cr\hidewidth$\scriptstyle\cdot$\hidewidth}}}% \scriptstyle
    {\mathrel{\ooalign{$\scriptscriptstyle\sqsubset$\cr\hidewidth$\scriptscriptstyle\cdot$\hidewidth}}}% \scriptscriptstyle
}

\begin{document}

$A \sqsubset B_{A \sqsubset B_{A \sqsubset B}}$

$A \sqsubsetcdot B_{A \sqsubsetcdot B_{A \sqsubsetcdot B}}$

\end{document}
```